# Passing an array to JavaScript filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Let's say I have an array of objects like this:

```
someObj: [
    {
        name: "Obj1",
        type: "a"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj2",
        type: "b"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj3",
        type: "c"
    }
]
```

Now I have a function that should return an array of objects from the `someObj` array if the parameters passed have the same `type` property. The thing is the parameter passed is an array and I'm not sure how to make that comparison.

```
function filter(types) {
  var filtered = someObj.filter(function(item) {

    return item.type == ???

  });       

  return filtered;  
}

filter(["a", "c"]);
```

How do I compare each item in the array parameter that's passed to item.type so that if they're equal, then the filter function would return to me an array like so:

```
[
 {
    name: "Obj1",
    type: "a"
 },
 {
    name: "Obj3",
    type: "c"
 }
]
```

Comment: `return types.includes(item.type)`?... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes or, if you don't like `includes`, you can always use the fancy indexOf: `return types.indexOf(item.type) > -1`.

Comment: Minor thing to add, you could just return the expression `return someObj.filter(...)` instead of creating a variable and then returning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search for the type.

ES5 with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
return types.indexOf(item.type) !== -1;
```

ES6 with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
return types.includes(item.type);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check the type:

```js
let someObj = [
    {name: "Obj1",type: "a"},
    {name: "Obj2",type: "b"},
    {name: "Obj3",type: "c"}
]       

function filter(types) {
  return someObj.filter(function(item) {
    return types.includes(item.type)
  }); 
}

console.log(filter(["a", "c"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a long winded mildly old-fashioned way:

```js
var someObj = [
    {
        name: "Obj1",
        type: "a"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj2",
        type: "b"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj3",
        type: "c"
    }
];


function filter(types) {
  var filtered = someObj.filter(function(item) {
  if ( types.indexOf(item.type) >= 0 )
    {
     return item;
    }

  });       

  return filtered;  
}

var x = filter(["a", "c"]);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6 syntax you could use the following:

```js
var someObj = [
    {
        name: "Obj1",
        type: "a"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj2",
        type: "b"
    },
    {
        name: "Obj3",
        type: "c"
    }
]

function filter(types){
  return someObj.filter(obj => types.includes(obj.type))
}

console.log(filter(["a", "c"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a reduce function here:

```
function filter(someObj, types) {
    return someObj.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        return types.includes(obj.type)? [...acc, obj] : acc 
    }, [])
}
```